# How can I get data from a website with Java?

Tags: java, android, web-scraping, jsoup

Hey I want to get a data from a Website. I had tried a lot but I dont get it.

This is the Website 
https://fortnitetracker.com/profile/psn/Julianpjp

I want the wins

My Code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        final String url = "https://fortnitetracker.com/profile/psn/Julianpjp";
        final Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

        for (Element row : document.select("div#profile")) {
            final String siege = row.select("trn_defstat_value").text();
            System.out.println(siege);

        }
    }
```

The is the value that I want

```
<div class="trn-defstat__value">5</div>
```

This are the higher element

```
<div id="profile" class="trn_profil>
```

Comment: I dont know fortenite at all. But there seems to be a web api at https://fortnitetracker.com/site-api

Answer (score 1):

`select()` expects a CSS selector. You're passing `"trn_defstat_value"`. This would select an element *named* `trn_defstat_value`:

```
<trn_defstat_value>...</trn_defstat_value>
```

You want to select the element which has a given *CSS class*. And the class is named `trn-defstat__value`, not `trn_defstat_value`. So the proper selector is thus `".trn-defstat__value"`.

Note that you're iterating over all the divs with the ID "profile", but by definition of n ID, there can be only one. And you're not iterating through the elements with the class `trn-defstat__value`, but there are many of them.

Comment: I've amended my answer.

Comment: You're right. Do you have an idea how I could do it that I get the right value

Comment: It's the fourth element with that class. You could use that. Or you could use its sibling element which contains the test "Victoires" (in French)